# Paypal payment execution failure modes

Tags: paypal, transactions

I'm currently in the process of implementing a Paypal payment receiver (using the REST API) for digital goods, and doing so in an environment without any support for two-phase commits or anything like that, so I'm wondering how to make it as robust as possible.

I cannot find anything in the documentation about expected failure modes. Does payment execution have expected failure modes that I should be looking out for, or is it supposed to always work as long as network errors or other unusual things do not happen? If there are no expected failure modes, I would be okay with simply delivering the goods before the payment is actually executed and then manually resolving any failed executions (at least in the short run). If there are expected failure modes, on the other hand, I'd need to try and think of something more complex.

Comment: Are you asking for a listing of [Rest API Common Error messages](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#errors)

Comment: @pp_MSI_Jenn: Not quite; more precisely, I'm wondering whether any of those should be expected during the execution call of a payment. As a more general question, I'm wondering how to build a robust solution without the possibility of something like two-phase commits, so as to avoid either executing payment while not delivering items due to errors on that end, or delivering items without executing payment due to errors on that end.